# How to get rid of division by zero errors in a vector field?

Tags: plotting, physics

Im currently learning Mathematica and have little to no expirence.
What im trying to do is plotting certain Fieldlines of a Dipol-Vectorfield.

I found a Method that works as long as no line aproaches the converging Pole.
How can I stop the Line from a Division Zero Error without stopping all other Lines.

```
nres = 14;
c = 9.5; (*<-this stops all Lines not just the ones with 1/0*)

Field[x_, y_] = 
  Grad[-1/10/Sqrt[x^2 + (y - 5)^2] + 1/Sqrt[x^2 + (y + 5)^2], {x, y}];
nf[x_, y_] = Normalize[Field[x, y]];

s = Table[
  NDSolve[{{x'[t], y'[t]} == nf[x[t], y[t]], 
    x[0] == Cos[2 Pi/nres*i]/10, y[0] == 5 + Sin[2 Pi/nres*i]/10}, {x,y}, {t, 0, c}], {i, 1, nres}]

Animate[Show[Graphics[{PointSize[0.001],
    Red, 
    Point[Flatten[
      Table[Table[{x[t/20], y[t/20]} /. s[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, 
         nres}], {t, 0, c*20}], 1]], PointSize[0.01],
    Blue, Point[Table[{x[t], y[t]} /. s[[i]][[1]], {i, 1, nres}]],
    Black, Point[{{0, 5}, {0, -5}}]
    }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}]
  ], {t, 0, c}, AnimationRunning -> False, AnimationRate -> .5]
```

[image: Gif of Fieldlines that I activly have to stop before reaching the Pole.]